# How to click an array of links in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm new to puppeteer, trying to understand how it works by writing a simple scraping job.

## What I plan to do

Plan is simple:

1. goto a page,
2. then extract all `<li>` links under a `<ul>` tag
3. click each `<li>` link and take a screenshot of the target page.

## How I implement it

Code goes as follows,

```
  await page.goto('http://some.url.com');                 // step-1
  const a_elems = await page.$$('li.some_css_class a');   // step-2

  for (var i=0; i<a_elems.length; i++) {                  // step-3
    const elem = a_elems[i];
    await Promise.all([
      elem.click(),
      page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})   // click each link and wait page loading
    ]);
    await page.screenshot({path: `${IMG_FOLDER}/${txt}.png`});

    await page.goBack({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});      // go back to previous page so that we could click next link
    console.log(`clicked link = ${txt}`);
  }
```

## What is wrong & Need help

However, the above code only could do with the first link in `a_elems`, and when the `for-loop` comes to the 2nd link, the code breaks with error saying

```
(node:40606) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is detached from document
    at ElementHandle._scrollIntoViewIfNeeded (.../.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/JSHandle.js:203:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async ElementHandle.click (.../.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/JSHandle.js:282:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async main (.../test.js:34:5)
  -- ASYNC --
    at ElementHandle.<anonymous> (.../.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at main (.../test.js:35:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I suspect that the execution context of `page` has already changed after the first link is clicked, even though I called `page.goBack` to previous page, but it doesn't give me the previous execution context.

Not sure if my speculation is right or wrong, and couldn't find any similar issue out there, hope I could get some help here, thanks!

If there could be even better implementation to achieve my plan, please let me know.

Comment: Do those links have some javascript attached to it or they are normal links with an href?

Comment: @hardkoded, they are normal links with an href, but relative url, not absolute ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about the elements losing its context when you `goBack`. That's not going to work.
But, as you commented, you can grab the `href` from the element and start from there:

```js
for (var i=0; i<a_elems.length; i++) {                  // step-3
  const elem = a_elems[i];
  const href = await page.evaluate(e => e.href, elem); //Chrome will return the absolute URL
  const newPage = await browser.newPage();
  await newPage.goto(href);
  await newPage.screenshot({path: `${IMG_FOLDER}/${txt}.png`});
  await newPage.close();
  console.log(`clicked link = ${txt}`);
}
```

You could even do this in parallel, although there is an internal queue for screenshots.

Comment: Great, and thanks for pointing out the `absolution url` thing.

Comment: Oh BTW, what if links have some javascript attached to it? Require a different solution?

Comment: That would require a different approach. For instance, trying to see if those links have some id attached, so then it would be a matter of trying to integrate those IDs instead of elements.